# Where can I get Windows2003 SP2 FileStream HOTFIX?

Tags: windows, sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I was installing SqlFailover Cluster, at one stage before installing SQL Server it shows:

> Windows2003 FileStream HOTFIX failed.

So I think this is not installed. Where can I get it?

Answer (score 2):

This is the hotfix you need - [MS KB937444](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/937444) - its one of the hotfixes you have to request, but you can do so through the webpage now rather than phoning.